# Excel VBA Scope Large Files

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Excel 2013 / Win7

Goal: To determine the size: #Rows/#Cols for worksheets too large for excel.

I tried using:

```
Dim sh as worksheet
For each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'These are just my preferred ways of finding the ending points.
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    BlahBlah 'code that prints LastRow and LastCol to my userform
Next sh
```

This works fine, but it only gives me stats for sheets <= the max excel row count

So playing with the files changing the extension from .xlsx to .zip and going to xl/Worksheets/sheet1.xml I noticed this line: `"<dimension ref="A3:C178"/>'`What I'm hoping for is a way to grab this for each sheet via vba to scope the sheet that way, but I can't fin a way to grab this ref.

Comment: How were these worksheets created in the first place? Are they actually very large csv files?

Comment: I'm not sure, I got them as .xlsx files - but it's evident that they contain more information then they're presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try last cell instead? 
Also, why don't you take this value prior to turning the .xls to .zip?

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

LastRow = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastColumn = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

Comment: I did take the value prior to converting - I was just curious if I could find the range in the xml, once I did I began looking for a method of extracting the range from the xml via vba.

Comment: I'll try your way - there's a million ways to skin this cat, I just prefer the method I'm using.

If your way will count the truncated rows then that's awesome - but seeing the "xlCellTypeLastCell" I'd wager it'll return the same thing mine does - the excel limit.

Comment: To get it from the xml, try to open it in a workbook, then look for the text dimension ref=" and do lefts and right to get the text between the ""

Comment: I can't find how to read the xml from inside the workbook via vba

Comment: You can't, you need to open it as a workbook, like so: 
Workbooks.Open ("'webadress'htp://google.com") could be local paths or so